# How perform query that delete elements from nested array in MongoDb using Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following mongoDB object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3f32a4e17c5739bccb9115"),
    "name" : "John",
    "friends" : [
            {
                    "name" : "Paul"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "Lisa"
            }
    ]
}
```

I need to delete some element from it. In native mongodb query it looks like

```
 db.users.update({}, {$pull: {friends: {name:"Lisa"}}})
```

But how can I do this via Morhia API?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by using:

```
Query<Group> query = getDatastore().createQuery(Group.class);
UpdateOperations<Group> ops = getDatastore().createUpdateOperations(Group.class)
                .removeAll("friends", new BasicDBObject("name", "Lisa"));
getDatastore().update(query, ops);
```